# Populating a column with sequential values

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

Thank you in advance!

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c(1:20)*2.5)
   Time
1   2.5
2   5.0
3   7.5
4  10.0
5  12.5
6  15.0
7  17.5
8  20.0
9  22.5
10 25.0
11 27.5
12 30.0
13 32.5
14 35.0
15 37.5
16 40.0
17 42.5
18 45.0
19 47.5
20 50.0
```

For every 5 seconds, I want to populate a new variable `Trial` with a sequential value starting from 1 as such:

```
   Time Trial
1   2.5     1
2   5.0     1
3   7.5     2
4  10.0     2
5  12.5     3
6  15.0     3
7  17.5     4
8  20.0     4
9  22.5     5
10 25.0     5
11 27.5     6
12 30.0     6
13 32.5     7
14 35.0     7
15 37.5     8
16 40.0     8
17 42.5     9
18 45.0     9
19 47.5    10
20 50.0    10
```

I'd like to do this using for loops, as I'm working with nested lists in my real dataset.
Here's my code so far, and it's not working (all the values are populated as 10):

```
n = seq(1:10)
for (j in length(n)){
 data <- data %>%
    mutate(Trial = case_when(Time%%5 < 5 ~ n[j]))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
data$Trial = ((data$Time - 1e-9) %/% 5) + 1
```

> I'd like to do this using for loops

Okay,

```
for(now_in_a_loop in 1) {
   data$Trial = ((data$Time - 1e-9) %/% 5) + 1
}
```

---

An issue with your attempt is a common typo - you need to add the `1:` to get `for(j in 1:length(n))`. But I think there are more issues... if you need help making this work with lists, post a small reproducible example of the list structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to derive the trial value from the time value, this loop might be of interest to you:

```r
data <- data.frame(time = c(1:20) * 2.5)

for(row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  data[row, "trial"] <- ceiling(data[row, "time"] / 5)
}

data
#>    time trial
#> 1   2.5     1
#> 2   5.0     1
#> 3   7.5     2
#> 4  10.0     2
#> 5  12.5     3
#> 6  15.0     3
#> 7  17.5     4
#> 8  20.0     4
#> 9  22.5     5
#> 10 25.0     5
#> 11 27.5     6
#> 12 30.0     6
#> 13 32.5     7
#> 14 35.0     7
#> 15 37.5     8
#> 16 40.0     8
#> 17 42.5     9
#> 18 45.0     9
#> 19 47.5    10
#> 20 50.0    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: But of course this is vectorized too, so `data[, "trial"] <- ceiling(data[, "time"] / 5)` will work just fine - no loop needed.